# Redshift - UNION ALL Messing the columns

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have two tables, Table A and Table B.

1. Table A has 4 columns (Date, Qnty, Price, Total)
2. Table B has 4 columns (Date, Qnty, Price, Total)
3. I am doing Table A UNION ALL Table B
4. In my result, all the Fact values are the same. For instance, Qnty has Price column value, Price has Price column value, Total has Price column value. 
   This is a very strange behavior by Redshift.

I have just given the example my production table has 40 columns and around 1.2B rows.

Answer (score 1):

List the columns explicitly and in the same order:

```
select Date, Qnty, Price, Total
from a
union all
select Date, Qnty, Price, Total
from b;
```

SQL assigns the columns by the *ordering* in a `union all` -- not by the name.  When you use `select *` the ordering is based on the order the columns are defined in each table.  And if the order is not the same, the results will be confused.

Comment: I have listed all the columns explicitly.

Comment: @NAData . . . Be sure they are in the same order.

Comment: They are in the same order, I have checked those things before posting the question :)

Comment: Check the actual data in the database. It might be that a stray comma impacted a data load, so the columns are one-off, or possibly loaded in the wrong order. Run each `select Date, Qnty, Price, Total` individually and check that the data appears correct. Doing a `UNION ALL` should _not_ impact the results aside from joining them together.

Comment: @NAData . . . Then the data is not correct in one of the tables.

Comment: I have checked that as well. When I run individual unions, they work fine. Can data type mess things up?

Comment: Data is coming from the same table. The only difference in Table A and Table B is they have different WHERE conditions.